# AWS backup window

Tags: amazon-web-services, backup

I have a question about AWS backup window.

It says in the documentation that the default backup start at 5AM UTC and with the backup window of 8 hours.

I want to create backups of EC2 instance on every hour of the day which means I should have 24 backups at the end of a day. I have chosen the backup frequency to be hourly, start time to be 6:00PM UTC, start within 1 hours and completion time to be within 2 hours. From this setup, I just got 6 backups in one day.
So my question is, should I put 12am as the start time of the backup window to ensure 24 backups in a day ?

What exactly does it mean when it says that default AWS backup time is 5AM UTC with backup window of 8 hours? is 8 hours backup window start within time or it just means that backups can only happen within those 8 hours especially when we select hourly backups? That would mean that we would have only 8 backups per days.

Answer (score 0):

see Overlapping backup rules in [this doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-backup/latest/devguide/creating-a-backup-plan.html) it could be the reason you’re only getting 6 per day if you have other rules in addition to the hourly one

careful, complete within is only there to error the backup out if it exceeds the window, it doesn’t speed the backup up or anything like that

aws support clarified for me: since you are starting your backup job every day at 8AM, the backup jobs will run every hour starting at 8AM - 11:55 PM. From 12AM to 7:55 AM there will not be any jobs created.

so i changed my hourly job to start at 12:00am and start within 1 hour.  once i saved it the job view screen stopped displaying start time at all.